# Ruby: get the website data after logging into website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a website that I need to access and get the content so I can parse it. This site has no API so I just have to access from the front end. The browser prompts me to log into the website but I do not know how to do this in ruby.

This works for websites that do not require authentication. I can NOT turn the authentication off.

```
 file = open('https://website/')
 contents = file.read
```

Comment: This can be done using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html).

Comment: In addition to Mechanize, you might be looking for a web scraping framework like [Upton](https://github.com/propublica/upton), [Ronin](http://ronin-ruby.github.io/) or [Scrapify](https://github.com/sathish316/scrapify).

Comment: Im not sure those work since the browser itself is prompting for authentication. There is no option to log on in the site itself.

Comment: What do you mean by prompt? What does it look like? Is there a form to login? If so Mechanize should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples here [mechanize example](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html)

If you are looking at http authentication then a similar post is here [basic-and-form-authentication-with-mechanize-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291576/basic-and-form-authentication-with-mechanize-ruby)

Use mechanize to make life easier.

Comment: Starting to look at this now. This will work even if the auth is coming from the browser not the web page correct? https://www.evernote.com/shard/s53/sh/995a74ff-d7de-45af-a0a1-95185d21d96c/bf8afbf7353b5874fd9194bafd08a1d8

Comment: Correct. Mechanize can be used in various scenarios. e.g. HTTP Auth such as the one your link shows or a user/password authentication can be done.