# How to download specific links from a page with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a webpage with a list of names (which are regular links). When I click on the names of the first page, this opens up another page which has a list of files for download as links. I want to download only the links that end with fq.qz for all of the page1 links.

To do this I have been trying to use Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://myURL/'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.css('li')[2]['href']

doc.traverse do |el|
    [el[:src], el[:href]].grep(/\.(fq.gz)$/i).map{|l| URI.join(url, l).to_s}.each do |link|
        File.open(File.basename(link),'wb'){|f| f << open(link,'rb').read}
    end
end
```

However, I don't think this opens up each of the page 1 links to get the fq.gz ending files in the next level.

The format of the links I am interested in is:

```
<td><a href="/lablink/secure/DownloadFile.do?id=900636">SLX-7998.blabla.fq.gz</a></td>
```

I tried using this code which is heavily adapted from one of the answers below but nothing gets downloaded and I get the array as below

```
master_page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/).map {|link| link.click
link = agent.get(agent.page.uri.to_s)
if link.content.include?("fq.gz")
out_file = File.new("downloaded_file", "w")
out_file.puts(agent.get_file(link[:href]))
out_file.close
end

=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: So, are you having a problem locating these download links on a given page or are you just having a problem downloading / writing the files for them?

Comment: So I'm having trouble trying to traverse each page from the page 1 and then downloading from the hyperlink

Comment: Which page is page 1? Cause you mention two types of pages; one page for finding lists of files and then another page for the actual lists of files available for download.

Comment: Page 1 is the list of pages and each page on that list is a page 2 with a list of files for download

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you can't find all the download links from each list of downloadable files and you can't actually download / write the content of the download link to a file?

Comment: So I have one page that contains a list of links to other pages. The other pages each contain links that cause files to be downloaded.  I want to walk through the master page, access all the pages it links to and in each of these pages download files that end in fq.gz

Comment: Ok, sorry for all the back and forth. Was just trying to understand which part of the process you were having trouble doing, but I think I understand now.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I wasn't clearer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite broad. You don't show us a minimal example of the HTML you're talking about, and without that we have to use very broad, generic, code which probably won't help. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Also, `traverse` is rarely the right path to use: It's slower than using a XPath or CSS selector and `search` or `at`.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you could use [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize), which is a tool for automating interaction with web pages that uses Nokogiri as dependency. You could probably do something like this:

```
require 'mechanize'

$agent      = Mechanize.new
master_page = $agent.get("http://master_page")

master_page.search("a.download_list_link") do |download_list_link|
  download_list_page = $agent.get(download_list_link[:href])

  download_list_page.search("td > a") do |link|
    if link.content.include?("fq.gz")
      out_file = File.new("downloaded_file", "w")
      out_file.puts($agent.get_file(link[:href]))
      out_file.close
    end
  end
end
```

Some things that I wrote there will depend on the specific names of elements on the pages you're visiting, but I think that the general idea there will solve your problem.

Edit:

Regarding the errors you're getting with an array of `nil` objects, one problem that I see is that you forgot to close the block:

```
master_page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/).map {|link| link.click
...
# no terminating curly brace
```

Comment: OK. Small hiccough. If I need to add authentication do I just add agent.add_auth('http://genomicsequencing.cruk.cam.ac.uk:8080/lablink' ,'myUserName', 'myPassword') after the 3rd line of your code? When I do this, as part of #<Mechanize::Form I get {fields
    [text:0x3feb368e92f0 type: text name: j_username value: ]
    [field:0x3feb368e9110 type: password name: j_password value: ]}

Comment: @SebastianZeki Also, this question might be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291576/basic-and-form-authentication-with-mechanize-ruby

Comment: @SebastianZeki Did you end up getting anywhere with the authentication? I don't mean to be pushy; just curious.

Comment: Yes thank you for asking. My ruby is pretty awful so have been spending hours trying to sort this out. Had to change your code so see above for the code I created. In its current form I'm getting an error.

Comment: @SebastianZeki I saw one immediate error there with your code; updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basis for a quick search for anchors containing certain sub-strings in the linked-text:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<a href="http://foo">foo.fq.gz</a>
<a href="http://bar">bar.fq.gz</a>
<a href="http://baz">baz</a>
EOT

nodes = doc.search('a').select{ |node| node.text[/fq\.gz$/] }
```

At this point `nodes` is a NodeSet of Nodes that match the `/fq\.gz$/` pattern in their text:

```
nodes
# => [#(Element:0x3fd9818bda2c {
#       name = "a",
#       attributes = [
#         #(Attr:0x3fd982027060 { name = "href", value = "http://foo" })],
#       children = [ #(Text "foo.fq.gz")]
#       }),
#     #(Element:0x3fd9818bd928 {
#       name = "a",
#       attributes = [
#         #(Attr:0x3fd982035ef8 { name = "href", value = "http://bar" })],
#       children = [ #(Text "bar.fq.gz")]
#       })]
```

We can walk through those and extract just the `href` parameters:

```
hrefs = nodes.map{ |node| node['href'] }
```

Resulting in an array that can be iterated over:

```
hrefs
# => ["http://foo", "http://bar"]
```

You should be able to figure out the rest.